# How to access ForeignKey child model's ID? int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

i keep getting error:

Line number: 1 - int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'

Im trying to access the child models id to sort by the company instance for each store.  It works if i upload the data through the child model but trying to do the opposite throws errors?

model.py

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    store = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)

    # pylint: disable=R0903
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.store)

class Child(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    store = models.ForeignKey('Parent', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    rank = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default='')

    # pylint: disable=R0903
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.company)
```

admin.py

```
class ParentResource(resources.ModelResource):

    state = fields.Field(attribute='state', column_name='State')
    store = fields.Field(attribute='store', column_name='Store')
    company = fields.Field(attribute='company', column_name='Company', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Child, 'company'))

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        import_id_fields = ('store', 'state',)
        fields = ('store', 'state', 'company',)

    def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        company = row.get('Company')
        store = row.get('Store')
        store = Parent.objects.get_or_create(store=store)
        rank = row.get('Rank')
        company = Child.objects.get_or_create(store=store[0], company=company, rank=rank, id=id)

class ParentAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ChildInline]
    resource_class = ParentResource
    list_display = ['store', 'state']

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
```

full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/developer/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-JnJjjKhL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 499, in import_row
self.before_import_row(row, **kwargs)
File "/home/developer/boards/cms/money/admin.py", line 69, in before_import_row
company = Child.objects.get_or_create(store=store[0], company=company, rank=rank, id=id)
File "/home/developer/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-JnJjjKhL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/developer/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-JnJjjKhL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 486, in get_or_create
return self.get(**lookup), False
File "/home/developer/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-JnJjjKhL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 390, in get
clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/developer/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-JnJjjKhL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 844, in filter
return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/developer/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-JnJjjKhL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 862, in _filter_or_exclude
clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/home/developer/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-JnJjjKhL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1263, in add_q
clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
File "/home/developer/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-JnJjjKhL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1287, in _add_q
split_subq=split_subq,
File "/home/developer/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-JnJjjKhL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1225, in build_filter
condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
File "/home/developer/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-JnJjjKhL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1096, in build_lookup
lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
File "/home/developer/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-JnJjjKhL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 20, in __init__
self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
File "/home/developer/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-JnJjjKhL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 70, in get_prep_lookup
return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
File "/home/developer/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-JnJjjKhL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 965, in get_prep_value
return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Comment: What line are you getting this error on?

Comment: full traceback please

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Added the full traceback error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line below as `id` does not exist. If you want the id of the object, use `self.id`.

`company = Child.objects.get_or_create(store=store[0], company=company, rank=rank, id=id)`

This could be changed to:

`company = Child.objects.get_or_create(store=store[0], company=company, rank=rank, id=self.id)` or make it the id of the object you need, e.g. `store.id`.

Note: You shouldn't really need to use a `get_or_create` when using an `id` field. Since you don't want to manually store the `id` yourself if the field does not exist.

Comment: hmm when using self.id im running into error `Line number: 1 - 'Child' object has no attribute 'id'` - if i should use get or create to assign an ID, what should i use

Comment: I wouldn't have defined an id on the Child model, since Django would have created an id automatically for you. If store and company are enough, do you need to query with an id as well? It really depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: yeah sorry left out a alot of context.  I need to use the instance id because if there are multiple companies with the same rank then it throws an error even if its a different store.  so i was trying to query by the company instance id.  i can try to query the store for the company instance